# Save from a dropdown list

Tags: php, javascript

What I want to do is when someone selects a hotel name, days, guests and peak is to calculate them together and produce a sum, also I want to save to the database all of the things the user
selected including the sum...

Please someone help I do not know javascript very well!!!!

```
    var m = new Array("standard","premium","executive","presidential");//mania hotel 
var mp= new Array(17000,25000,38000,52000);

    if(n == 0)
{
    document.res.root.options.length = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<m.length; i++)
    {
        var o = new Option(m[i], mp[i] );
        document.res.root.options[i] = o;
    }
}

    function getPrice(){
    var guests = parseInt(document.res.Guest.value); 
    guests = 1;

    var price = (guests * 5) + (days * hotel);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java script array variable for price with respect to hotel name then on lost focus of day you can calculate the sum similar for other entries of lost focus or what you can do is you can write a function which will take care of all this and if all validation is successful then calculate the sum. Provided you must be having the price rates for each hotel before hitting submit button.